# See merge requests without assignee on GitLab

Tags: plugins, gitlab

GitLab allows us to see the issues and MR assigned to us but, is there a way (either by plugin or a filtering option) to **see on the board**, all the merge requests with/out assignee?

On the company that I work for, we have a restricted number of people that have the responsibility to accept MRs. When any of them are free to accept another MR, they look for one that has no assignee yet, but it's not user friendly having to open an issue from the board (which by the way is on the review column), open its related MRs and check if it's assigned. If there are lots of issues on the review column, this can be extremely annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot list unassigned MR from the Web interface, but you could retrieve this info through the API:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the search to see those tickets in the board, you can use the Chrom extension [GitLab Board Better](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbb-gitlab-board-better/fjhimlhfidegbajaoaagkogellknammf?ref=52366863) to create a shortcut in menu bar